# Targeting First and Last "li" in Each "ul"

Tags: jquery, navigation

I would like to target the first and last 'li' of a 'ul' using jQuery and add a class of "first" and "last" to them accordingly.

I know that using jQuery this is easy if its just a simple 'ul' but I am struggling with the right syntax if the 'ul' has more than one 'ul' nested in the parent 'ul'.

Here is an example of the html markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Top Level Item</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">First Sub-Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Last Sub-Item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">First Sub-Sub-Item</a>
                    <li><a href="#">Last Sub-Sub-Item</a></li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to target all of the first and last items of each sub-ul and apply a class to each of them.

Here is what I have been using but it is obviously not working as it is applying the class name to only the very first 'li' and the very last 'li'.

```
jQuery('.topmenu ul li ul li').first().addClass('first');
jQuery('.topmenu ul li ul li').last().addClass('last');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that everything you have shown is inside something with the class "topmenu". I would advise changing this to an ID if it's unique, and applying a class to the "first ul" so it doesn't have to be avoided algorithmically.

```
$('.topmenu').find('ul ul li:first-child').addClass('first');
$('.topmenu').find('ul ul li:last-child').addClass('last');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aBksB/2/

EDIT: to reflect comment

Comment: This will add the class to ALL `ul`s.  I believe he does not want it added to the parent `ul`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nKTtp/) using the code below.

```
$('ul li ul').find('>li:first').addClass('first').end()
    .find('>li:last').addClass('last');
```

Comment: This works as well ... and I like this solution better ... Thanks for the help! I look forward to contributing to others questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try using css selector first-child and last-child:

```
jQuery('.topmenu ul li ul li:first-child').addClass('first');
jQuery('.topmenu ul li ul li:last-child').addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `>` you can specify an imediate child, like this:

`$('ul>li').first()`

`$('ul>li').last()`

`ul>li` gets only the `li` nodes imediately inside an `ul` node.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `first-child` and `last-child`:

```
jQuery('.topmenu ul li ul li:first-child').addClass('first');
jQuery('.topmenu ul li ul li:last-child').addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selectors...

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ul class="myclass">
        <li>Items</li>
        <li>Items</li>
        <li>Items</li>
   </ul>

jQuery(".myclass li:last").addClass("last");
```

most of the time class to last child not added. The script works perfect if you want to add class to last child of li.